# Finding element by tag attribute that has multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following html:

```
<div class="displayBox grid_8" tags="Name:name;Title:title;Program:program;Client:client">
```

How can I find this element using the tags Name, Program and Client with Jquery?
I had been previously using:

```
 $("div[tags^='Name:" + SelectedExam + "']")
```

But this is no longer the case as that div had to change to include other tags.

Comment: I'd restructure the element so it was `data-name`, `data-title`, etc.. as separate attributes.

Comment: Well you're using a bespoke, unparsed syntax for data, so you're always going to struggle to query it. You'd need to do a `.filter()` and REGEX it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a constraint to keep all of the information in the "tags" attribute?

It would be much simpler to split into other attributes.

```
<div data-name="name" data-program="program"></div>
```

and so forth.

Comment: It's an assumption I am making, this was put in by someone else and I'm afraid to change it incase it breaks something elsewhere.

Comment: A fair assumption.

I would break from it if you can, but otherwise you are breaking away from the strengths of "css selecting". I would suggest adding a class to each of these types of elements, and hard looping to allow deeper inspection: $(".taggedDivs").each( <parse this for string and take apart>)

Comment: Used the data attributes with the tags, will probably remove the tags when I get time to.

Answer (score 1):

change the `^` in your selector to a `*`

the `^` means 'starts with', while the `*` means 'contains'

and close your selector with a semicolon, since your tags are separated by it. this way you will avoid selecting different tags that start the same, like  'apple' and 'apple-juice'

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/HjTsf/)**</kbd>

js:

```
$(function () {
    var SelectedExam="title";
    $("div[tags*='Title:" + SelectedExam + ";']").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think jQuery supports this (would be happy if someone corrects me). What I'd do is:

```
$("div[tags^='Name:']").each(function() {
  $div = $(this);
  $div.attr('tags').split(';').forEach(function(p) {
    pair = p.split(':');
    $div.attr(p[0], p[1]);
  });
});

// Now you should be able to select $("div[Name='val1'][Title='val2']")
```